# Epsilon-net of operator norm ball around Identity

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-geometry, eigenvalues, eigenvector, operator-norms

Suppose I look at the set of matrices which are invertible and satisfy
$$
\left\|A-Id\right\|_{op}<r
$$
for some $r<1$, where $Id$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix.  An $\epsilon$-net of such a set would consist of finitely many matrices which are each at least $\epsilon$ apart from each other in the operator norm, and satisfying that every other matrix in this ball is at least $\epsilon$ close to one of these.

**My question is this: what is the minimal cardinality of such a net?  It would be interesting to me if it were something strictly less than $\left(C/\epsilon\right)^n$.**

Comment: An $\epsilon$ ball has volume $\sim \epsilon^{n^2}$, so you need at least $\gtrsim (C/\epsilon)^{n^2}$ sets.